# Complete orthonormal system in P2(R)

Tags: orthonormal

Does someone knows a complete orthonormal system on $$P_2(R) := \{ax^2 + bx + c : a,b,c ∈ R\}$$ equiped with scalar product $$⟨p,q⟩ = p(−2)q(−2) + p(0)q(0) + p(2)q(2)$$ ?

Comment: I’m sure that someone does, but it looks like you’re meant to work it out for yourself. Show your own efforts at solving this problem. Where are you getting stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with $f(x)=x^2+dx+e$. Then
$$\begin{align}\langle1,f\rangle&=4-d+e+e+4+d+e=3e+8=0\\
\langle x,f\rangle&=-8+2d-2e+0+8+2d+2e=4d=0\end{align}$$
So we arrive at $e=-\frac83$ and $d=0$, so
$$p_2(x)=a\left(x^2-\frac83\right)$$
Then
$$\langle p,p\rangle=a^2\left(\left(\frac43\right)^2+\left(-\frac83\right)^2+\left(\frac43\right)^2\right)=\frac{32}3a^2=1$$
So we may let $a=\frac{\sqrt6}{8}$ and then
$$p_2(x)=\frac{\sqrt6}8\left(x^2-\frac83\right)$$
Oh, but you wanted a complete orthonormal system. We already can see that $\langle1,x\rangle=0$, so we only need worry about normalization. Simlilar to what we did above for $p_2(x)$ we can show that
$$p_0(x)=\frac1{\sqrt3}$$
$$p_1(x)=\frac1{\sqrt8}x$$
If course we can apply any orthogonal transformation to get other solutions. Another way is with the Lagrange basis:
$$\begin{align}q_{-2}(x)&=\frac{(x-0)(x-2)}{(-2-0)(-2-2)}=\frac18x(x-2)\\
q_{0}(x)&=\frac{(x+2)(x-2)}{(0+2)(0-2)}=-\frac14\left(x^2-4\right)\\
q_{2}(x)&=\frac{(x+2)(x-0)}{(2+2)(2-0)}=\frac18x(x+2)\end{align}$$